# Populate activities based on RecyclerView Selection

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I am working on a recipe or biography kind of app where I need to populate my activity only with different content but in the same activity layout.

I couldn't find a way I don’t need to create tons of different activities for each item selected in my RecyclerView.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to say you cant to create a new activity based on some text in the custom list item and this is your custom view holder class

```
public static class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener {

public TextView titleView;

public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
    super(itemLayoutView);
    titleView = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

In your **onClick()** method,Start an activity and pass in some extras like

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),ItemActivity.class);
         myIntent.putExtra("title",titleView.getText());
         startActivity(myIntent);

    }
```

Then create an activity class file that will represent your ItemActivity in my case **ItemActivity.java**

and in the **onCreate()** method, we can get our extras and use it the way we like.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_item);

    String title =this.getIntent().getStringExtra("title");

 }
```

You can now may be set it up as the title of your new activity actionbar like`actionBar.setTitle(title);`

Comment: Thank you so much. But how can I populate activity with different contents based on Recycler View Selection. What ı mean that is I am trying to make a biography app. There will be a lot of RecyclerView Items including great people and their pictures and names. I need to find a way to populate their life story in an activity without creating tons of activities.

Comment: Just use the same concept like instead of myIntent.putExtra("title",titleView.getText()); you may also use myIntent.putExtra("intVariableName", intValue); for integers like for drawable_resource_id.You can also pass lists and so much more